# How to indicate a popover trigger

Tags: popup

I have some columns with complex data in them and I think that a Twitter Bootstrap popover is the best way of providing an explanation.  (I am using bootstrap throughout the project).

Should I simply make the column heading an anchor, `<a href='#'>Heading</a>`, and attach the popover to it's on-click event?  Or is there a better way to identify the trigger for a popover?

The Twitter Bootstrap examples use a button, but I don't think that's the way to go in my case.  Is there any kind of standard?

Answer (score 3):

You can use visible cue to trigger interaction. A possible solution is on the picture. The information icon is rather standard way in your case.
[image]
Also it's better to supplement `click` event with `hover` one, because some users are afraid of unpredictable hyperlink behavior. They can think of column sorting or moving to other page, etc. So I use dotted underline to differentiate the link. From the other side, an icon doesn't bring a fear of changes. As the area of icon is rather small, there should be few accidentally hovering, so it wouldn't be annoying.

Icon usage is proven way to increase usability.

> Overall, we found that
> providing icons next to  hyperlink text is very helpful for users in
> reducing the  amount of time they take to finish their task, number of
> clicks they take to reach their target page and in optimizing  the
> path they take to the target page.
>
> It has been found that users take
> significantly less time  when both hyperlink text and corresponding
> icons are  provided compared to the conditions when only hyperlink
> text or only icons are present.

from [Impact of placing icons next to hyperlinks on
information-retrieval tasks on the web](http://mindmodeling.org/cogsci2010/papers/0669/paper0669.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Dotted underlines seem to be the most common way of indicating the availability of supplementary information, and is implied in the latest [draft HTML 5.1 documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-html51-20131029/rendering.html):

> abbr[title], acronym[title] { text-decoration: dotted underline; }

You might also implement a help-cursor (arrow with question-mark), especially if a click is needed. This helps to indicate that what might **look** like a link won't actually send the user anywhere else.

[image: Help cursor]